# Restrict specific nesting in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

tl;dr I don't want to allow nested tables in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnL6mmvk/3/)

I'm trying to limit the html allowed in my CKEditor as much as possible. One of the rules I'm trying to enforce is to only allow tables in the root and definitely no nested tables. There lies my problem...
I've tried using the `allowedContent`, `disallowedContent` config entries and strait up changing the `CKEDITOR.dtd`, nothing works so far.

```
// doesnt seem to do anything
// CKEDITOR.dtd.$blockLimit.table = 0;

// cannot create table at all
// CKEDITOR.dtd.td.table = 0;

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    customConfig: '',
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'blocks', groups: [ 'insert'] }
    ],
    removeButtons: 'Image,HorizontalRule,SpecialChar,Blockquote',
    // disallowedContent: {
    //     table: {
    //         match: function( element ) {
    //             no way to access what the parent element is
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
});
```

[Try the fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/qnL6mmvk/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution in the dtd after all. The problem where removing `table` from `CKEDITOR.dtd.td` resulted in not being able to create a table at all was imo a bug in CKEditor.

`CKEDITOR.dtd.td` points to the same object as `CKEDITOR.dtd.body` and some others as well. So if I want to change `CKEDITOR.dtd.td` **only** I need to make a copy of the object reference and work on that.

```
// using Lo-Dash to create a copy of the object
CKEDITOR.dtd.td = _.merge({}, CKEDITOR.dtd.td);
delete CKEDITOR.dtd.td.table;

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    customConfig: '',
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'blocks', groups: [ 'insert'] }
    ],
    removeButtons: 'Image,HorizontalRule,SpecialChar,Blockquote'
});
```

This gives the desired result of a greyed out button when the cursor is inside a table cell but a normal button when in the body.

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnL6mmvk/7/).

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnL6mmvk/4/) and now it removes nested table mark-up but leaves it's content:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    customConfig: '',
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'blocks', groups: [ 'insert'] }
    ],
    removeButtons: 'Image,HorizontalRule,SpecialChar,Blockquote',
    disallowedContent: {
         tr: {
             match: function( element ) {
                 var parentTableCount = 0;
                 for (var elem = element.parent; elem; elem = elem.parent)
                 {
                     if (elem.name == 'table')
                         parentTableCount++;

                     if (parentTableCount > 1)
                         return true;
                 }
             }
         },
         table: {
             match: function( element ) {
                 for (var elem = element.parent; elem; elem = elem.parent)
                 {
                     if (elem.name == 'table')
                         return true;
                 }
             }
         }
    }
});
```

You might want to adjust it for your needs as my example mostly showing how you can access parent elements. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your example neatly removes the table from the initial content, it however doesn't block adding a table in a cell while editing. While editing the `element.parent` seems to always be `undefined` no matter where the cursor is.